# How to add dropdownlist inside a input field text box with search property in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display the user with input text field with search button along with dropdown list.How can I add dropdown list in input field with search buuton in javascript?
Here is my code:

```js
var grp = angular.module("grpApp", [])
.controller("grpCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.groupList=["ram","rakesh","priya","rekha"];
 document.getElementById('multisearchInput').onfocus = function () {
            this.value = '';
            document.getElementById('formcontainer').style['border'] = '1px solid red';
        }

        document.getElementById('multisearchInput').onblur = function () {
                document.getElementById('formcontainer').style['border'] = 'none';
            }
            }
```

```html
 <div class="input-group" id="formcontainer">
                <div id="dropdowncontainer">

                    <select id="lists" ng-repeat="list in groupList|filter:search track by $index">
                        <option ng-bind="list"></option>
                    </select>

                </div>
                <div id="inputcontainer">
                    <input class="multisearchInput form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search friend.." ng-model="search" name="q" onFocus="this.value=''" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is this problem solved?

Comment: No.Uploaded image changed to default src image on refreshing or reloading the page.

Comment: Did not you call the API to get the updated value for the image src?

Comment: lol. this question is different from the one which you just posted, related to image..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903141/how-to-upload-an-image-that-doesnot-loose-uploaded-image-after-refreshing-the-pa

Comment: yes.sorry for the mistake